# Redirect to homepage after registration

Tags: php, html, forms

**Note : The question is not as simple as the title suggests. However since I could not think of anything better, i typed what i think is closest to my problem.**

I have an html page(lets call it `firstpage`) which has 2 forms( since form processing is via php, it is basically a php page). The php code for the page is as [here](http://pastie.org/8536928) . One form is for a registered user to login and one form is for the registration of a new user. Following multiple online tutorials I followed the procedure of submitting the form to the page itself using `method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>"` . However since Im doing this for both the forms, i now have following issues:

1.The [php file](http://pastie.org/8536934) which checks various constraints of a new user during registration is executed as soon as i load `firstpage` which should ideally be executed only when the user fills up the form and clicks on register. Due to this a bunch of php messges strings are always displayed on loading `firstpage`

2.I do not know how to redirect to the homepage which is the page that should appear when a new registration is successfully completed and  also when a registered user is logged in. Any help will be REALLY helpfull. php script for to check for a registered user is  [here](http://pastie.org/8536942)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the conditions **`1`** & **`2`**, Follow this

### 1.

Replace your **`if`** statement from

```
if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && (!empty($_POST['action']))):
```

to

```
if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && isset($_POST['action']) && (!empty($_POST['action']))):

//Assuming $_POST['action'] is the name of your submit button.
```

### 2.

Make use of the **`header`** to redirect to certain page

Something like this

```
if(isset( $_SESSION['userid'] ))
{
    $message = 'Users is already logged in';
    header("location:profile.php");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: the name of my button in case of both forms is ` action ` . Do i change that?

Comment: No don't,  just see the edited code with the `isset` construct.

Answer (score 1):

As for 1. the usual way to go around this is having boolean variables to keep track of the validity of each field (say, `isEmailValid`) that are by default set to true *until* the form was submitted.

```
$isEmailValid = true;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $isEmailValid = false;

    function verifyEmail($email);
}
```

As for your 2nd question, after all checks are done and you stored the record of the new user into the database you could do just

```
header('Location: index.php');
exit();
```